# Randomised Array is not appended to id tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I have set a method to randomised an array of images. These randomised images will then be appended to the id tag within the html body. I have set 2 image id and have tried to append the randomised image array to the image id.

However, no images are being displayed.

Hence, what has been done wrong? please help.

Code:

```js
var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/Brands/A.png", "lib/img/Brands/C.png", "lib/img/Brands/B.png"];

function Game_Congrats() {



  //Randomised Brand Offer
  //Auto populate into brand container once randomised
  for (i = 0; i < $('#list').find('img').length; i++) {

    random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);

    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
    BrandNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex, 1);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).show();
  }
}

}
```

```css
.GameWinBrand_Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 950px;
  left: 286px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 580px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.GameWinBrand_innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.GameWinBrand_Container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.GameWinBrand_Container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #5e5767;
}
.GameWinBrand_Container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #5e5767;
}
```

```html
<div class="GameWinBrand_Container">
  <div id="BrandWinlist" class="GameWinBrand_innerScroll">
    <img id="GameBrand_1" style="width:250px; height:230px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" onclick="selectBrand('1');">
    <img id="GameBrand_2" style="width:250px; height:230px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('2');">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first thing thats wrong is your snippet has a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Comment: Your jQuery selector starts with "#Brand_" but the elements have "GameBrand_".

Comment: Does your loop even run?  I don't see any img tags in your HTML that are matched by your selector: i.e. `$('#list').find('img').length` is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of wrong id references:

First of all your loop does not execute, because you do not have an element with id `list`.

Secondly you don't have image elements with id `Brand_1`, ... etc.

So change your code to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < $('#BrandWinlist').find('img').length; i++) {
    random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
    BrandNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex, 1);
    $('#GameBrand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand).show();
}
```

Note that you can chain the call to `show`.

Also the selector and loop can be written more concisely as follows:

```
$('#BrandWinlist > img').each(function (i, img) {
    random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
    BrandNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex, 1);
    $(img).attr('src', Brand).show();
});
```

And as a bonus, you can `splice` and get the removed element in one go:

```
    var Brand = BrandNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex, 1)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The id of `img` tags starts like `GameBrand`.

Change this:

```
 $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);
```

to:

```
 $('#GameBrand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);
```